# android - NFC in fragments, onNewIntent isn't called after I return from another activity

Tags: android, fragment, nfc, onnewintent

I have an application that uses the NFC. I have a MainActivity that extends a BaseActivity. In the BaseActivity, on the "onCreate" method, I initialize the nfc.

```
---- Base Activity ----
....
private void initializeNfc() {
        NfcManager manager = (NfcManager) getSystemService(NFC_SERVICE);
        nfcAdapter = manager.getDefaultAdapter();
        IntentFilter filterNdef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
            try {
                filterNdef.addDataScheme(CipherClient.nfcDataScheme());
                filterNdef.addDataAuthority(CipherClient.nfcDataAuthority(), null);
                filterNdef.addDataPath(CipherClient.nfcDataPath(), PatternMatcher.PATTERN_SIMPLE_GLOB);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Errore", e);
                return;
            }
            intents = new IntentFilter[]{filterNdef};
            pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
            techs = new String[][]{new String[]{NfcF.class.getName()}};

            }
```

In the MainActivity I have a slider with 4 tabs and in each tab I have a fragment. The fragment where I can use the nfc is only the number 0 (NfcFragment).

The first time I start the MainActivity, the "onCreate" method is called and the first fragment (FirstFragment) is displayed. If I'm not in the NfcFragment and I approach a nfc tag, I get a toast that says "move to the NfcFragment to use the nfc".

```
---- MainActivity ----

viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onPageSelected - position: "+position);
                currentTabPosition = position;

                if(position == 0) {
                    // I am in the NFC tab. So I set true the flag
                    if (verifyNfc()) {
                        nfcON = true;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    // I'm not on the nfc tab, so I set false the flag
                    nfcON = false;

                    enableForegroundDispatch();

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

private boolean verifyNfc() {
        boolean nfcEnabled = nfcAdapter.isEnabled();
        if (!nfcEnabled) {
            Log.i(TAG, "NFC not activated");
            // NFC disabled
            Toast....
        }
        return nfcEnabled;
    }
```

If I move to the NfcFragment and approach a nfc tag, the "onNewIntent" method is called and I open a new activity (MyNewActivity). From MyNewActivity I press back, "onBackPressed" is called and I do "finish()".

```
---- MainActivity ----

@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onNewIntent");

        if (nfcON) {
            // nfcHandlingInProgress is a variable that checks if you are already using the nfc (in read or write) or is free
            if (!nfcHandlingInProgress) {

                nfcHandlingInProgress = true;
                handleIntent(intent);
            }
            else {

                String message = "NFC already in use, wait a few moments and try again";
                Log.d(TAG, message);
                Toast...
            }
        }
        else {
            // If I am not on the tab that contains the NFC fragment, I do not continue and invite the user to move to this tab.
            String message = "To use the NFC move to the NFC section";
            Log.d(TAG, message);
            Toast...
        }
    }


private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "handleIntent");

..... // if the nfc scheme, data and authority are known, I start a new activity

        nfcHandlingInProgress = false;

        Intent i = new Intent(this, MyNewActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPause");
        super.onPause();

        disableForegroundDispatch();
    }

public void disableForegroundDispatch(){
        Log.i(TAG, "disableForegroundDispatch");

        try {
            if (nfcAdapter != null) {
                nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Toast...
        }
    }
```

From MyNewActivity I go back and find myself again in the MainActivity (which is already instantiated and therefore is not called "onCreate" but "onResume").

```
---- MyNewActivity ----

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }


---- MainActivity ----

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume");
        super.onResume();

       enableForegroundDispatch();

        if(currentTabPosition == 0)
            nfcON = true;
        else
            nfcON = false;
    }

public void enableForegroundDispatch(){
        Log.i(TAG, "enableForegroundDispatch");

        try {
            if (nfcAdapter != null) {
                if (nfcAdapter.isEnabled())
                    nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pending, intents, techs);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Toast...
        }

    }
```

NOW, if I go to a fragment that isn't NfcFragment, it should display a toast right? Instead no, from any fragment, if I approach a nfc tag, MyNewActivity is opened. The problem is that the onNewIntent method is no longer called, it is bypassed.

I used in "onPause" the method disableForegroundDispatch and in "onResume" the method enableForegroundDispatch correctly. I also used the flags FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP, FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TASK etc.

This behavior is solved if I re-initialize the nfc in the method onResume of MainActivity or if I do startActivity(this, MainActivity.class) in the method "onBackPressed" of MyNewActivity, because is called onCreate method and new instance of the activity is created. But it's a work around and I wouldn't want to initialize the nfc repeatedly.

```
---- MyNewActivity ----
// Solution 1 to which I do not want to resort because it is heavy to load 4 tabs together in the main activity
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }



---- MainActivity ----
// Solution 2 that I don't want to use because onResume is called more than once
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume");
        super.onResume();

       // NEW NEW NEW
       initializeNFC();     // <----------------------------

       enableForegroundDispatch();

        if(currentTabPosition == 0)
            nfcON = true;
        else
            nfcON = false;
    }
```

Please could someone give me a solution to initialize the nfc one time and intercept the nfc tag always with the onNewIntent method? Even if I come back to the MainActivity from MyNewActivity and so is called onResume method and not onCreate method.

Any suggestions ? Thank you very much

Comment: suggestion 1: please put your code so that we don't have to use our imagination

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57920613/android-nfc-in-tabs-viewpager-fragments-onnewintent-isnt-called-after-onpa